# ActionBarDrawerToggle's openDrawerContentDescRes and closeDrawerContentDescRes

Tags: android, toolbar, actionbardrawertoggle

The [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) doesn't seem to use the `openDrawerContentDescRes` and `closeDrawerContentDescRes` arguments. Here's my example code:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, // Activity
    drawerLayout,
    R.string.main_drawer_open,
    R.string.main_drawer_close
);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

This issue originally came to me from a QA engineer who was unable to find a way to reference the navigation drawer toggle from a calabash console, so that is what I'm trying to address. I hadn't touched this code in a while, so my first thought was that I needed to set an id or a contentDescription on the view so that calabash could reference it. However, much to my surprise, I'm already setting them.

To see if the problem could be isolated to calabash, I opened Hierarchy Viewer only to find the view's contentDescription property was null, see [screenshot of null contentDescription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0D55.png).

Has anyone else had trouble with this and/or been able to solve it?